# Overlay on VLC Player not displaying in IE11 in Windowless mode

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video, vlc

I'm embedding the VLC player on a webpage, the container in which it resides has a header with the option to launch a popup dialog. I cannot get the dialog to display on top of the player in Internet Explorer 11. It renders correctly in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Player:

```
<object width="0" height="0" id="vlc0" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" events="True" z-index="0">
<embed width="100%" height="380" id="vlcEmb" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" target="rtsp://172.27.1.75/live.sdp" loop="no" autoplay="yes" z-index="-1" windowless="true" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2">
```

Div:

```
<div id="editID" class="btn-primary pull-right headerButton" style="z-index:100">

</div>
```

I've ensured the z-index of the div to be overlayed is higher than the player.

Is this a bug in with the player and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the reason is that we don't really support windowless in the ActiveX plugin. So far, it was implemented only for the NPAPI plugin used by all the other competing browsers. Of course it would be technically feasible to do that, but no volunteer stepped up to write the missing bits so far. This might change in the future, but I can't give any estimate when.